# Navigation from ViewPager Fragment to Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to make 3 ViewPager sets of 3 pages each. Each page will have a fragment controlled by pagerAdapter. Inside each fragment I m thinking putting 2 buttons which can take you to an another ViewPager set. 
So inside fragment I will implement onClickListener and in Click method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageButtonChoice1:

            break;

        case R.id.imageButtonChoice2:

            break;
    }
}
```

So do I have to close the whole activity which controls the 3 ViewPagerAdapters and reload it? 
or
should I put these navigation buttons in the activity and not in the fragment?
How by clicking an imagebutton can go to another viewpager set?

Comment: why are you creating 3 ViewPagers with 3 pages each, when you can create 1 viewpager with 9 pages and navigate between pages? If this is so, how they are placed in activity?

Comment: Because each viewpager has different topic

Comment: If the viewpager overlaps each other, you can set their visibility accordingly. can you post your xml code?

Answer (score 0):

Each button can launch an activity which has a set of different ViewPager.
In the activity you need impleten ViewPager.

This is sample (In this example, an object is passed between the Fragment ):

```
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    Instalacion instalacion;
    ArrayList<Actividad> arrayListActividades;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Instalacion instalacion, ArrayList<Actividad> arrayListActividades) {
        super(fm);
        this.instalacion = instalacion;
        this.arrayListActividades = arrayListActividades;

    }

    @Override  
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {  
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();  

        switch (position) {  
        case 0:  

            fragment = new InfoInstalacionFragment1();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("key", (Instalacion)instalacion);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;  
        case 1: 
            fragment = new InfoInstalacionFragment2();
            Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
            bundle2.putSerializable("key", (Instalacion) instalacion);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle2);
            return  fragment;
        case 2:  
            fragment = new InfoInstalacionFragment3();
            Bundle bundle3 = new Bundle();
            bundle3.putSerializable("key", (ArrayList)arrayListActividades);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle3);
            return fragment;  


            return fragment; 

        default:  
            break;  
        }  
        return fragment;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);

        }


        return null;
    }
```

onCreate method:

```
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), instalacion, arrayListActividades);

        // Instanciamos nuestro ViewPager
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        //habilitar el listenner
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        // Establecemos el Adapter
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter)
```

Comment: Wouldnt be better if the PagerAdapters were separate classes to be easier controlled and edited?

Comment: I solved it by reloading activity which controlled PagerAdapters